# How to relate the Frobenius norm of matrix with the trace of the laplacian matrix of a connected graph $G$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, graph-laplacian

How to show this equality.

Let $L$ be the Laplacian matrix of a graph $G$ with eigenvalues $0,1,2..,n-1$, then this equality holds.
$$\|{L}\|_{F}^{2} = \mbox{trace} \left( L^{2} \right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2$$

where $i=0,1,2,..,n$  are the eigenvalues of the Laplacian matrix of $G$.

Comment: It's fairly direct from the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm

Comment: You really need to fix the notation in the sum, it's a mess as written. Once you write out the formula properly, use the fact that the trace of any matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @cmk . i have a little bit confusion about the following equality .                                                               $$\|{L}\|_{F}^{2}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} di^2+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$